# How to revove all whitespces at the end of string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to remove all white spaces at the end of string (empty line and tab and everything spaces at the end)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String test = "This is test message.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + " \n"
                + "";
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("[\\s\\n]*$", ""));
    }
```

I tried using trip() and stripTrailing() methods but it did not remove empty lines hence trying with regex. But it is not removing. Any idea why it is not working?

[image]

Comment: have you tried just trimming the String?

Comment: I guess Trim will not remove empty lines

Comment: You "guess". But have you tried it?

Comment: Tried (test.trim()) it is not removing empty lines

Comment: Then you might be using some odd JDK. It removes them without a problem when I test it. So ... how did you test it? By just running test.trim();? you have to check the result of that, not retest the test variable

Comment: I am using java 11. tested using System.out.println(test.trim());. but it is not removed.

Comment: I just tried `.trim()` and it prints "This is a test message.", so if it doesn't for you, we're going to need to see your attempt at trying `trim()`.

Comment: `.trim()` is working (at least in OpenJDK 11). Note that `println` (short for print _line_) will add one newline again.

Comment: Added a screen shot for your reference. I see all the empty lines after using trip and stripTrailing

Comment: `trim()`works perfectly fine, see an example here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/vJm

Comment: There is no "trip" method for strings in Java.  Please show us your (alleged) example using `trim()`.  Note spelling!!

Comment: please don't add code as screenshots. Always as code. I'm pretty sure you didn't try trip(), since you would 've noticed that wouldn't compile.

Comment: Your stripTrailing example does not produce the output you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way to settle this is to **prove** that `trim()` works:

```
$ cat Test.java 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "This is test message.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + " \n"
                + "";
        System.out.println(test.trim());
    }
}
$ java Test.java
This is test message.
$
```

If it doesn't work for you, then maybe you are not recompiling your code, or something like that.

For earlier versions of Java use `javac Test.java` to compile and then `java Test` to run it.  You will get the same output as shown.

Comment: Note that I did not use a screenshot ... so you will be able to copy and paste the code into a file and compile / run it for yourself.  (Do it ... I dare you :-) )